# Is it possible to use elasticsearch synonyms dynamically?

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I'm struggling trying to implement synonyms in elasticsearch queries.
As i've seen in [Synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html), i could create a filter when creating the index with the following structure:

```
"sinonimos": {
  "type": "synonym",
  "explicit": false,
  "synonyms_path": "sinonimos.txt"
}
```

This filter is being used in the analyzer, and if i understood it right, any of the words in the "sinonimos.txt" would be considered a match if my query was "celular", am i wrong?

The file "sinonimos.txt" is created in the elasticsearch/config folder, and has the following content:

```
smartphone, telefone => celular
```

Knowing that i have 4 different values in my index field called "descricao":

- celular
- smartphone
- telefone
- cellphone

When i modify the "sinonimos.txt" file with a new word "cellphone", then using the `_reload_search_analyzers` API in my index, shouldn't that word be queried too?

The main question here is, how can i implement this synonyms in a dinamic way, so when i add a new synonym to a word, or a new list of synonyms, i don't have to reindex the current index?

In this [Elastic Blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms), they say

> Synonyms are used in analyzers that can be used at index time or at search time.

The difference between them is clear and also said in [Elastic Blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms):

> Index-time synonyms have several disadvantages:

- The index might get bigger, because all synonyms must be indexed.
- Search scoring, which relies on term statistics, might suffer because synonyms are also counted, > and the statistics for less common words become skewed.
- Synonym rules can’t be changed for existing documents without reindexing.

> Using synonyms in search-time analyzers on the other hand doesn’t have many of the above mentioned problems:

- The index size is unaffected.
- The term statistics in the corpus stay the same.
- Changes in the synonym rules don’t require reindexing of documents.

The idea of the dynamicity is that i will add/remove new words / lists of words all the time, and would like to do that in a dynamic way so i dont have to reindex or _close > update > _open the index. Is that possible?

Edit:
The problem was that i was trying to use the synonym analyzer as the index analyzer, instead of using it as the search_analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some useful information about Elasticsearch synonyms token filter

```
"filter": {
  "synonym": {
    "type": "synonym_graph",
    "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",  
    "updateable": true                        
  }
}
```

To update the synonyms list update the synonym.txt file and call `POST /index_name/_reload_search_analyzers` and clear the request cache `POST /index_name/_cache/clear?request=true`
Because reloading affects every node with an index shard, it's important to update the synonym file on every data node in the cluster, including nodes that don’t contain a shard replica, before using this API. This ensures the synonym file is updated everywhere in the cluster in case shards are relocated in the future.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-reload-analyzers.html#indices-reload-analyzers-api-desc

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [ "synonym" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym_graph",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",  
            "updateable": true                        
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "my_synonyms"              
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Recommendation: Set the `profile:true` and check the results. You will see the matched fields for your search_analyzer.

```
GET test_synonym/_search
{
  "profile": true,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "test search",
        "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use updatable true you will be able to [reload the analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-reload-analyzers.html) without closing the index.

Doc:

> You can use the reload search analyzers API to pick up changes to
> synonym files used in the synonym_graph or synonym token filter of a
> search analyzer. To be eligible, the token filter must have an
> updateable flag of true and only be used in search analyzers.